# Get0ingt value from Node doesnt work, android

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

Everything is ok. Getting xml from internet, parsing to Document but when I am trying to get some value from node ()and some between one node (Very cloudy.)

```
private void parseWeather(Document srcDoc) throws Exception {

        for (int a = 0; a < srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("record").getLength(); a++){
            Node recordNode = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("record").item(a);
            Node temperatureNode = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("temperature").item(a);
            Node windNode = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("wind").item(a);
            Node bioNode = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("bio").item(a);

            RECORD = recordNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("date").getNodeValue().toString();
            TEMPERATURE = temperatureNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("min").getNodeValue().toString();
            WIND = windNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("speed").getNodeValue().toString();
            BIO = bioNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("value").getNodeValue().toString();
            Element element= (Element) srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("record").item(a);
            NodeList status = element.getElementsByTagName("status");
            NodeList text = element.getElementsByTagName("text");

            Node statusNode = status.item(0);
            Node textNode = text.item(0);
            String statusText = statusNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
            String textText = textNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();



            Log.e("Values", "STatus is " + statusText + " and text is " + textText);

        }

    }
```

and this is xml file

```
<root>
<forecast>
     <record date="24-10-2012">
<temperature max="17" min="3" unit="°C" />
<wind speed="2 až 5" direction="SV" unit="m/s" />
<bio value="2" />
<status symbol="3">Fair</status>
<text>Very fair today.</text>
<warnings />
     </record>
     <record date="25-10-2012">
<temperature max="16" min="2" unit="°C" />
<wind speed="2 až 5" direction="Juhozápadný" unit="m/s" />
<bio value="3" />
<status symbol="3">Cloudy</status>
<text>Very cloudy tommorow. </text>
<warnings />
      </record>
<record date="25-10-2012">
<temperature max="16" min="2" unit="°C" />
<wind speed="2 až 5" direction="Juhozápadný" unit="m/s" />
<bio value="3" />
<status symbol="3">Cloudy</status>
<text>Very cloudy tommorow. </text>
<warnings />
      </record>
```

I get the output for record, temperature, wind a bio but not for status and text. And this loop will do only ones.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

status and text don't have any children because they aren't node lists, they are just nodes. try getting them as nodes and using `status.getNodeValue()` instead.

Comment: Im sorry but it doesnt work. It actually want to change the type of element.getElementsByTagName("status"); to ((Document )element).getElementsByTagName("status"); but still. It crashed every time on the variable element.

Comment: this kind of stuff is why i hate parsing XML in java. any chance you can switch to JSON? it's more lightweight and parsing is much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I found the solution. Now i need to just change the encoding of output. But still thanks.

Comment: you should post the solution so if anyone else has the same problem, they can find it

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.sk/2011/05/dom-parsing-example.html

It doesnt look like so easy